# How to pass some NON-ASCII character in keytool

Tags: keystore, keytool

I'm trying to install CA Certification in which I am trying to pass some non-ascii character like `£`,etc and in keytool but I am getting this error:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII
>                   at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKey.(PBEKey.java:63)
>                   at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKeyFactory.engineGenerateSecret(PBEKeyFactory.java:116)

This is for openSUSE base which has Java 7 running on it.

Comment: What is the keytool command you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 2):

For the non-ascii symbol java have historical bug which they haven’t fix till now (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6979740)